# Alexa App on iPhone 4 / iOS 7.1.2 - Can't find “alexa” button

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an old iPhone 4 that I want to use via WiFi in my car to use Alexa to play Spotify. I installed the Alexa app from the App Store. Because the last version of iOS for the iPhone 4 is version 7.1.2, the App Store prompted me to download the last version of the app that worked with my version of iOS (1.24.202645.0). It installed fine, and I was able to connect it to my Alexa account with no problems.

The challenge now is, I can't find the Alexa button in the app. There is a home screen and a hamburger menu button at the top that brings up what looks like the setup menu, but no Alexa button to tell Alexa to do things. Is the screen too short? Has anyone else successfully used Alexa on an iPhone 4? Can you give me the pointers I need to make it work?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  I thought, and I could be wrong, that the Alexa app only works with iOS 9 and above right now.  The button to talk to it should be at the bottom, middle of the screen.  It looks like you're in Airplane Mode in the screenshot so maybe the button is disabled?

Comment: @fsb WLAN is active

Comment: @nohillside Yea, I saw that but this is an old app and I'm not sure how they coded it so I thought I'd just ask.  According to [Amazon's Help Site](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=202015600), only iOS 9 and above are supported so this could be the reason it doesn't show the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app for the iPhone prior to iOS 9 is for practice as per:
[image]